# Laravel 5.8 voyager translator not working when paginated

Tags: laravel-5.8, voyager

When I use without paginate, the Voyager Translatable trait works fine.

```
$data = Post::where('status', 1)->get()->translate();
```

But, when I change it to paginate:

```
$data = Post::where('status', 1)->paginate(15)->translate();
```

in view:

```
$data->links()
```

then it gives an error in blade view:

```
Method TCG\Voyager\Translator\Collection::links does not exist
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

i did it that:

```
public function getTranslated(Builder $query, string $lang) : array {
    $data = $query->paginate();
    $dataArray = $data->toArray();
    $translatedData = $data->translate($lang);
    $dataArray['data'] = $translatedData->toArray();
    return $dataArray;
}
```